# Need help with page title (Static front page)

Tags: title, bloginfo, wp-title

I need some help with the code to put inside the `<title>` to generate the following:

- **Static front page:** Should just be the `bloginfo('name')`
- **All other pages:** Should be `wp_title()` | `bloginfo('name')`

**EDIT**
I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<title><?php if(is_front_page() ) { bloginfo('name') } else { wp_title() | bloginfo('name') } ?></title>
```

Comment: What file contains this code? Is anything working?

Answer (score 1):

The conditional tag `is_front_page()` is used to specifically check for a static front page, so you should be able to use that to switch between your title formats

```
<title>
    <?php if(is_front_page()) {
        bloginfo('name');
    } else { 
        wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
    }; ?>
</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot the ";"

should be:

```
<title>
  <?php if(is_front_page()) {
    bloginfo('name');
  } else { 
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
  } ?>
</title>
```